# In Maui, how to add iOS simulators to Visual Studio on Windows?

Tags: ios, visual-studio, maui

I have .Net 7 Maui App and I'm trying to deploy the app to an iOS simulator.

Visual Studio is on Windows. And the app is build with the help of a remote Mac.

After some deployment attempts I'm getting the error:

> Please select a valid device before running the application.

When checking the iOS simulators, I don't have any. How can I add them?

[image]

I also have "Remote Simulator to Windows" Checked.

[image]

Comment: Note to whoever suggested this be closed for reason "Not about programming or software development": that close reason makes no sense. As the close reason states in its detailed description, questions about *"... tools primarily used for software development"* are valid for StackOverflow. This question is about using the tool visual-studio to develop Maui software.

Comment: Personally, I always first attach a monitor and keyboard to the remote mac, and download VS for Mac. Once you've successfully built and run on mac's iOS simulator, you are more likely to be successful getting the PC to do so remotely. Reason: XCode and its simulator is correctly set up after this step.

Comment: What is your Xcode version? If you are using `Xcode14.3`, you need upgrade your VS to `Visual Studio 2022 version 17.6`.